# How to add the position index as the suffix into the columns in R?

Tags: r

I just have a data.frame like this:

```
             x           y            z
1          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7
```

How can I change the column name to this:

```
           x_1         y_2          z_3
1          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 1:3)
colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(df), "_", seq(ncol(df)))

#  x_1 y_2 z_3
#1   1   1   1
#2   2   2   2
#3   3   3   3
```

Or if you prefer `paste`:

```r
paste(colnames(df), seq(ncol(df)), sep = "_")
```

Also works with `seq_along`:

```r
paste(colnames(df), seq_along(df), sep = "_")
```

Comment: ok, thanks. haha, this is also a new approach.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` approach using `rename_with` like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "             x           y            z
1          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rename_with( ~ paste0(.x, '_', seq_along(.x)))
#>   x_1 y_2 z_3
#> 1 5.1 3.5 1.4
#> 2 4.9 3.0 1.4
#> 3 4.7 3.2 1.3
#> 4 4.6 3.1 1.5
#> 5 5.0 3.6 1.4
#> 6 5.4 3.9 1.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a super simple method, this is also an option, though its probably less favorable compared to the other answers here if you have a lot of variables that need changing:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Emulate Data ####
df <- read.table(text = "             x           y            z
1          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7", header = TRUE)

#### Rename Variables ####
df %>% 
  rename(X_1 = x,
         Y_2 = y,
         Z_3 = z)
```

Which gives you this:

```
  X_1 Y_2 Z_3
1 5.1 3.5 1.4
2 4.9 3.0 1.4
3 4.7 3.2 1.3
4 4.6 3.1 1.5
5 5.0 3.6 1.4
6 5.4 3.9 1.7
```

Comment: ok.. thanks, but actually I have a huge data frame with 10 thousand columns. This approach might be hardful for me to do it.

Comment: Understandable. Like I said the other answers are probably more useful for your case, just figured I'd stick this here in the case you have smaller data frames that require quick fixes in the future.